# Invalid allocation size? c++

Tags: c++

I got three files:

Text.h

```
#include <string>

namespace w3
{
    class Text
    {
        std::string file_name;
        std::string* handler;
        int records;

    public:
        Text();
        Text(char*);
        size_t size() const;
        Text(const Text& );
        Text& operator=(const Text&);
        Text(Text&&);
        Text&& operator=(Text &&);
        ~Text();
    };
}
```

Text.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include "Text.h"

namespace w3
{
    Text::Text()
    {
        file_name = "";
        handler = nullptr;
        records = 0;
    }

    Text::Text(char* file)
    {
        file_name = file;

        if (file[0]='\0')
        {
            file_name=" ";
            std::cout << "can not find file name !!" <<std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::fstream f(file_name);
            std::string line;

            if (f.is_open()) //ERROR
            {
                while (std::getline(f,line,'\n'))
                {
                    records++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "file not open !!" <<std::endl;
            }

            std::string* handle = new std::string[size()];

            f.clear();
            f.seekg(0,std::ios::beg);

            int counter = 0;

            while (std::getline(f,line,'\n'))
            {
                if (counter != records)
                {
                    handle[counter]=line;
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    size_t Text::size() const
    {
        return (size_t)records;
    }

    Text::Text(const Text& src)
    {
        std::string file_name = src.file_name;

        int no_of_rec = src.records;

        if (src.handler != nullptr)
        {
            handler = new std::string[src.size()];
            handler = src.handler;
        }
        else
        {
            handler = nullptr;
        }
    }

    Text& Text::operator=(const Text& src)
    {
        if (this != &src)
        {
            int no_of_rec = src.records;

            std::string file_name = src.file_name;

            if (src.handler != nullptr)
            {
                handler = new std::string[src.size()];
                handler=src.handler;
            }
            else
            {
                handler = nullptr;
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Text::Text(Text&& src)
    {
        file_name=src.file_name;

        handler = src.handler;

        records = src.records;

        src.file_name = " ";
        src.handler = nullptr;
        src.records = 0;
    }

    Text&& Text::operator=(Text&& src)
    {
        if (&src != this)
        {
            file_name = src.file_name;

            handler = src.handler;

            records = src.records;

            src.file_name = " ";

            src.handler = nullptr;

            src.records = 0;

        }
        return std::move(*this);
    }

    Text::~Text()
    {
        //delete [] handler;
    }
}
```

w3.cpp

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <iomanip>
 #include <utility>
 #include <ctime>
 #include "Text.h"
 #define TIME(start, end) double((end) - (start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC

 int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
     if (argc == 1) {
         std::cerr << argv[0] << ": missing file operand\n";
         return 1;
     }
     else if (argc != 2) {
         std::cerr << argv[0] << ": too many arguments\n";
         return 2;
     }
     std::clock_t cs, ce;
     {
         std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3);
         cs = std::clock();
         w3::Text a;
         ce = std::clock();
         std::cout << "Constructor      " << TIME(cs, ce) << " seconds"; 
         std::cout << " - a.size = " << a.size() << std::endl;

         cs = std::clock();
         w3::Text b(argv[1]);
         ce = std::clock();
         std::cout << "Constructor      " << TIME(cs, ce) << " seconds";
         std::cout << " - b.size = " << b.size() << std::endl;

         cs = std::clock();
         a = b;
         ce = std::clock();
         std::cout << "Copy Assignment  " << TIME(cs, ce) << " seconds";
         std::cout << " - a.size = " << a.size() << std::endl;

         cs = std::clock();
         a = std::move(b);
         ce = std::clock();
         std::cout << "Move Assignment  " << TIME(cs, ce) << " seconds";
         std::cout << " - a.size = " << a.size() << std::endl;

         cs = std::clock();
         w3::Text c = a;
         ce = std::clock();
         std::cout << "Copy Constructor " << TIME(cs, ce) << " seconds";
         std::cout << " - c.size = " << c.size() << std::endl;

         cs = std::clock();
         w3::Text d = std::move(a);
         ce = std::clock();
         std::cout << "Move Constructor " << TIME(cs, ce) << " seconds";
         std::cout << " - d.size = " << d.size() << std::endl;

         cs = std::clock();
     }
     ce = std::clock();
     std::cout << "Destructor       " << TIME(cs, ce) << " seconds\n";
 }
```

I get an error at the function Text::Text(char* file) at the line of if (f.is_open()).

Now, I debugged and concluded that the error results in a Invalid allocation size.

When I further inspected the error, I noticed that the records value would have an absurd negative number such as -858993460!

I need pointers on how to fix this.

The text file that is being opened is rather a really large file...

Thanks.

Comment: `The text file that is being opened is rather a really large file...` More than 2GB? (random guess, have not looked at the code yet)

Comment: Why not use a `std::vector<std::string>` instead of a raw array?

Comment: @Shrooms You are creating local `handle` variable and do not assign to `handler` member.

Comment: Where is your _minimal_ test case?

Comment: @Shrooms Get rid of this stuff:  `std::string* handle = new std::string[size()];` and lines like that.  Just simply use `std::vector<std::string>` and don't be surprised if all of your problems go away.  You also won't need that assignment operator or copy constructor.  You would have half the code you have now, and with no bugs.

Comment: The workshop makes me have an assignment operator and copy constructor :(

Comment: I don't know what the "workshop" is, but that assignment operator need not be coded that way if you have a working copy constructor and destructor (all it needs to be is a 4 line function).  And why did you comment out the line in your destructor?  It doesn't make your program work better or with less bugs.  Also, you need to post the command-line you used to run your program.  You're taking command-line arguments (`argv[1]`).

Comment: Off topic nag: Often the best and only documentation a programmer's going to get is the header file, so the header file should be complete and helpful to readers. `Text(char*);` is legal, but it gives the user few hints as to what that `char*` parameter is going to be used for and what they should provide. I recommend throwing the poor sucker a bone and giving parameters descriptive names.

Comment: use `vector<string>` and have assignment operator etc. with default body

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by saying that you could eliminate major portions of this code, plus have little chance of bugs occurring if you used `std::vector<std::string>` as the `handler` member, instead of `std::string*`.

Having said that, the one glaring error is that you have a faulty copy constructor.  You are not copying all of the information from the `Text` object that is passed to you.  You left out the `file_name` and `records` members, leaving them uninitialized.

In addition, your `handler` member variable is set incorrectly -- you allocate memory, and then you set `this->handler` again to a pointer to the passed-in object's `handler` member.  This is totally incorrect.

The copy constructor should allocate a new array, and then copy the strings from the passed-in object to the new object's `handler` member.

Your copy constructor should look something like this:

```
Text::Text(const Text& src) : file_name(src.file_name),
                              records(src.records),
                              handler(nullptr)
{
    if ( src.handler )
    {
        handler = new std::string[src.records];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < src.records; ++i )
            handler[i] = src.handler[i];
    }
}
```

Once you have this, remove the comment from the destructor -- `delete [] handler;` should be uncommented.

Once this is all done, the assignment operator is simple:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
Text& operator=(const Text& src)
{
   Text tmp(src);
   std::swap(tmp.handler, handler);
   std::swap(tmp.records, records);
   std::swap(tmp.file_name, file_name);
   return *this;
}
```

This uses the [copy / swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom).  Basically all that this does is create a temporary object from the passed-in object, and swap out its internals with `this`'s internals.  Then the temporary object dies with the old data.